View commit that is on a different branch
Is there a way to view a commit within the sidebar (via VS Code or GitLens or some other extension) that is on a different branch than the one you are on?

You should be able to view the history (circled clock icon on the left) and change the branch drop down to "All Branches" to view commits that are present on other branches:

From here, you can view each file as it was in the commit (using the "View" option in the lower right of screenshot).
